# How to get part of a citation to show in bibliography only?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I'm using biblatex-chicago for my bibliography. Just recently I decided I wanted to add descriptions for some of my manuscript sources so that someone looking them up in the bibliography would have an idea of what they were; I used the "addendum" field to hold this information, e.g.:

```
@misc{BnF000,
entrysubtype = {archival},
author = {{Bibliothèque nationale de France, Paris}},
shortauthor = {BnF},
title = {MS nouv. acq. fr. 000},
addendum = {collection on local history, 16th c.},
keywords = {unpublished},
}
```

The citations are pretty straightforward in the document:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

    \addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

    \begin{document}

    Here is a sentence.\autocite{BnF000}

    \end{document}
```

However, this of course adds the description to the footnotes, where it's not needed. Can I make this line only apply to the bibliography? Thanks very much!

Comment: A minimal document is definitely needed.

Comment: OK, I've put a very basic one in--if there's anything else you want to see, let me know!

Comment: It's also needed how you load `biblatex`; the document class you're using, too.

Comment: Added the class (sorry, the info's stored in several places and I didn't grab it all at once). For biblatex there's nothing other than the package I included, I don't think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `addendum` option for `biblatex-chicago` to control exactly this.  By default it is set to `true`.  Making it `false` produces:

[image: Footnote sample]

with

[image: Sample References]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is a sentence.\autocite{BnF000}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

where `Bibliography.bib` is

```
@Misc{BnF000,
  entrysubtype = {archival},
  author =   {{Bibliothèque nationale de France, Paris}},
  shortauthor =  {BnF},
  title =    {MS nouv. acq. fr. 000},
  addendum =     {collection on local history, 16th c.},
  keywords =     {unpublished}
}
```

Comment: Oh, this looks just like what I want! Thank you! Only, now it's giving me "Package keyval Error: addendum undefined", and stops compiling. I've tried trashing the aux files--any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to update your distribution - I have `biblatex-chicago 2013/10/29 v 2.8`, which probably also requires an up-to-date `biblatex`.

Comment: Yep, that sorted it! Perfect, thank you very much.

Out of curiosity, is is possible to make individual addenda show/not show in the footnotes, or is it an all or nothing proposition?

Comment: You can do that with `{\toggletrue{cms@addendum}\autocite{BnF000}}`, but beware of interaction with the ibid tracker.