# How can I exclude addendums from footnotes?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, footnotes

I use addendums inside my .bib file to annotate each source, but I only want these annotations to appear in the bibliography that is printed at the end of the document. Naturally, when I cite the same sources in my document they appear in the footnotes.  Is there a way that I can keep them in the bibliography but exclude them from the footnotes? Here is my code:

**Latex:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed nunc pulvinar, iaculis sapien at, 
volutpat erat. Vivamus consectetur ipsum eu purus pretium volutpat. Donec feugiat luctus enim, nec 
maximus libero facilisis a. Donec venenatis tincidunt iaculis. \autocite{engles} Nulla viverra ligula 
in eleifend euismod. Pellentesque accumsan orci vitae odio consequat blandit. Proin tristique viverra 
nunc, a tristique diam eleifend vel. Praesent nibh quam, fermentum nec auctor in, dignissim non est.

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Bib File:**

```
@misc{engles,
author = {Frederick Engels},
title = {The Principles of Communism},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1847/11/prin-com.htm}},
month = {Oct},
year = {1847},
keywords = {primary},
addendum = {This is a test addendum. This addendum should be included in the bibliography, but not in the footnotes.}
}
```

**Result:**

[This is the resulting pdf.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e_Ow5o6Wxkm3yGEXJxiiq1FA1H-a6yOX/view?usp=sharing)

Any suggestions are appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` has an option for that. With `addendum=false,` you can suppress the `addendum` field in citations. It will still be printed in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber, addendum=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{engels,
  author   = {Frederick Engels},
  title    = {The Principles of Communism},
  url      = {https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1847/11/prin-com.htm},
  month    = oct,
  year     = {1847},
  keywords = {primary},
  addendum = {This is a test addendum.
              This addendum should be included in the bibliography,
              but not in the footnotes.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for the example
Lorem \autocite{engels}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote: " Frederick Engels, “The Principles of Communism,” October 1847, https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1847/11/prin-com.htm.", bib: "Engels, Frederick. “The Principles of Communism,” October 1847. This is a test addendum. This addendum should be included in the bibliography, but not in the footnotes. https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1847/11/prin-com.htm."]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201403/35864 (but as always it is much easier to find these sort of things if you know the answer already).

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.  Thank you so much, that fixed it right up.  Sorry I didn't find that post earlier, thank you for sharing the link.